# Finding Margin Using Values from Three Tables VBA, SQL

Tags: sql, excel, vba, db2

Been stuck on this for months. Here are the example tables, the code I am using, and the issues I am running into:

```
ITEM

MFGR | CLR | PAT | Desc1 | Desc2 | Price | Cost
-----|-----|-----|-------|-------|-------|------
MMM  | 001 | 001 | BLAH  | BLAH  | MMM01 | MMM01
MMM  | 002 | 002 | BLAH  | BLAH  | MMM02 | MMM02
MMM  | 003 | 003 | BLAH  | BLAH  | MMM03 | MMM03
MMM  | 004 | 004 | BLAH  | BLAH  | MMM04 | MMM04
MMM  | 005 | 005 | BLAH  | BLAH  | MMM04 | MMM05


PRICE
/* The P1, P2, P3, etc. are prices for different quantities */
/* T1 tier is just better pricing and quantity breaks for high volume customer */

PRICE | TIER | LISTP | P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 | P5 | P6 | P7 | P8 | P9 | P10 | P11 | P12
------|------|-------|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|-----|-----|-----
MMM01 |  LP  |  $10  |$10 | $9 | $8 | $7 | $6 |    |    |    |    |     |     |     
MMM01 |  T1  |  $10  |$8  | $7 | $6 | $5 | $4 |    |    |    |    |     |     |
MMM02 |  LP  |  $20  |$20 |$18 |$16 |$14 |$12 |    |    |    |    |     |     |
MMM02 |  T1  |  $20  |$16 |$14 |$12 |$10 | $8 |    |    |    |    |     |     |
....


COST

 COST | LASTC 
------|-------
MMM01 | $5
MMM02 | $10
```

So I am using VBA and SQL to import directly into Excel from an IBM DB2 database. I don't have any other options or applications available to me for whatever reason, so this is simply what I have to do.

What I am trying to accomplish is to generate a list of items who have a margin--whether it is list price, a price tier, or a quantity break--that is below a GPM specified with a VBA InputBox. Any item that has any of its price points below X needs to show up on the report.

This is the code that I have been using and the two issues I have run into that I will subsequently explain:

```
SELECT i.MFGR || i.CLR || i.PAT as Item, i.DESC1 as Description1, 
i.DESC2 as Description2, i.PRICE as PClass, i.COST as CClass, p.TIER as Tier, 
c.LASTC as Cost, p.LISTP as List, ((p.LISTP-c.LASTC)/p.LISTP) as GPM, p.P2 as Price2, 
((p.P2-c.LASTC)/p.P2) as GPM2, p.P3 as Price3, ((p.P3-c.LASTC)/p.P3) as GPM3, 
p.P4 as Price4, ((p.P4-c.LASTC)/p.P4) as GPM4, p.P5 as Price5, 
((p.P5-c.LASTC)/p.P5) as GPM5, p.P6 as Price6, ((p.P6-c.LASTC)/p.P6) as GPM6, 
p.P7 as Price7, ((p.P7-c.LASTC)/p.P7) as GPM7, p.P8 as Price8, 
((p.P8-c.LASTC)/p.P8) as GPM8, p.P9 as Price9, ((p.P9-c.LASTC)/p.P9) as GPM9, 
p.P10 as Price10, ((p.P10-c.LASTC)/p.P10) as GPM10, p.P11 as Price11, 
((p.P11-c.LASTC)/p.P11) as GPM11, p.P12 as Price12, ((p.P12-c.TLASTC)/p.P12) as GPM12 
FROM ITEM i
LEFT JOIN COST c
     ON i.COST = c.COST
LEFT JOIN PRICE p
     ON i.PRICE = p.PRICE
WHERE (((p.LIST-c.LASTC)/p.LIST) < '" & margin & "') 
ORDER BY i.MFGR || i.CLR || i.PAT
```

First issue: this shows the price breaks for tier LP, but not for the T1 tier. It will just show the LISTP column only for T1. It should show all the P1, P2, P3, etc. that comes after it. Yes, I have verified my T1 files do have P1, P2, etc. values.

But this query doesn't give me what I really want anyway because I want it to pull any item with any price point below a certain GPM. So I modify the where statement to the following:

```
/* I will eventually add margin calculations for P3, P4, etc. */
/* but can't even get this to work, so not point in it yet */

WHERE (((p.LIST-c.LASTC)/p.LIST) < '" & margin & "') OR 
(((p.P2-c.LASTC)/p.P2) < '" & margin & "' )
```

So even the margin I input is 20% and the list price is over %20, but the P2 is below, the item should still come up, right? Nope. I get an error every time that says: Run-time error '1004': General ODBC Error. I usually get this if I enter the column name wrong, but I can assure you, I have have done my due diligence and all my column names are correct, data that should be importing has been verified to actually be there, I have adjusted data to get predictable results, tried every combination of parenthesis, etc.

If I change the OR to AND, the ODBC error goes away, but that isn't what I want to do since that is saying if both LP and P2 are below the margin... I want either or.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4360/8) should put you on the right track

This targets SQL Server but I believe all the commands are standard so should work in DB2.

```
DECLARE @TARGET FLOAT = 0.2

SELECT P.PRICE, P.TIER, P.P, P.PRICES, C.LCOST, (P.PRICES-C.LCOST)/P.PRICES MARGIN, @TARGET TARGET
FROM   (SELECT PRICE, TIER, P, PRICES
        FROM   PRICE
        UNPIVOT
        (
          PRICES 
          FOR P IN (LISTP, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9, P10, P11, P12)
        ) U
       WHERE PRICES <> 0) P
       LEFT JOIN
       COST C on P.PRICE=C.COST
WHERE  (P.PRICES-C.LCOST)/P.PRICES < @TARGET;
```

What this does is `UNPIVOT` the table that you have so you get the columns with the prices converted to rows - the join is then trivial.

Comment: Hi, I can't really get this to work. It seems to omit the use of the ITEM table which is the mediator between PRICE and COST. The reason being is that P.PRICE does not always equal C.COST, so the ITEM is needed to have the correct price and cost display for that item.